# Syntax error при инициализации массива

Tags: php

```
$w = array($w['ssid'], $date, $w['hostname'], $w['ip'], ,$w['nickname'],
           $w['text'], $w['dialogID'], $w['money'], $w['score'], $w['pin'], 
           $w['dname'], $_SERVER['remote_addr']);
```

Ошибка:

> PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')'

Почему в данном конкретном случае возникает ошибка? Как-то можно аналогично реализовать наполнение массива?

Comment: Подозреваю, что дело в этом: `$w['ip'], ,$w['nickname'],`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нельзя просто взять и пропустить значение. Попробуйте так:

```
..$w['ip'], NULL, $w['nickname']..
```

Альтернативный вариант, полагающийся на [обработку переменных](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing):

```
$w = explode(',', "$w[ssid],$date,$w[hostname],$w[ip],,$w[nickname],$w[text],$w[dialogID],$w[money],$w[score],$w[pin],$w[dname],$_SERVER[remote_addr]");
```

Тут можно две запятые подряд, т.к. сначала формируется строка со значениями через запятую, а затем она бьётся на массив, используя запятые как разделители. Но если одно из значений содержит запятую, всё летит в тартары.

Comment: тьфу, точно, спасибо.

Comment: Там вообще не подразумевалось никакого значения, даже Null, просто похоже лишний раз ткнул запятую.